# How to iterate over two dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas

let's say that I have a function:

```
def testfunction (x):
      blablblaalbal
           return c[1]
```

Now I have two different data frames which I haven't merged yet.

```
x = [df1, df2]
```

How can I apply the testfunction on x which returns the two c[1] values?

Furthermore, i would like to save these two c [1] values into a csv doc.

Comment: This question is like the movie "The Call": you don't see this end coming and it is not related to the beginning.

Comment: This is very hard to follow, please post some actual code.

Comment: Do you mean to say, you need to apply testfunction on df1 and df2 individually and store the result somewhere?

Comment: Like `y = map(testfunction, x)` ? This will apply testfunction to every item of the iterable you pass and return a list of the results.

Comment: Thank you very much Brian for your answer! I just spent 2.5 hours on this problem. I thought that I need to apply a "for loop"...

Comment: @user21988 Posted as an answer. Feel free to accept if it helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the built-in [map](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) function

```
y = map(testfunction, x)
```

This will apply the function `testfunction` to every item in `x` and return a list of the results.